# Bash formating string | Azure CLI | Etag | IfMatch | azure devops

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, devops, etag

So I am trying to automatically update an azure devops wiki using azure CLI. In order to do so I need to get the wiki etag:

```bash
az devops wiki page show\
        --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
        --wiki my_project.wiki \
        --query 'eTag'
```

Output:

```bash
"\"1156501f9cxxxxxbdca3456d6xxxxdd63\""
```

And if I manually copy this output and past in the command

```bash
az devops wiki page update\
    --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
    --wiki my_project.wiki \
    --version "\"1156501f9cxxxxxbdca3456d6xxxxdd63\"" \
    --file-path test.md \
    --encoding utf-8
```

It works perfectly.

Great, now just need to automate that, right?

```
etag=$(
    az devops wiki page show\
        --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
        --wiki my_project.wiki \
        --query 'eTag'
    )

az devops wiki page update\
    --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
    --wiki my_project.wiki \
    --version $etag \
    --file-path test.md \
    --encoding utf-8 \
    --debug &> thebug
```

Wrong, look at the error.

Error message:

```
Pre-condition `IfMatch` header provided in the request is an invalid page version. Please provide the version of the wiki page as the `IfMatch` header for the request.
Parameter name: IfMatch
```

If you look at the debug option, you can see why the error, it's because the etag it is not set correctly:

```
version that show on debug: ... '--version', '"\\"1156501f9cxxxxxbdca3456d6xxxxdd63\\""', ...
what should be: "\"1156501f9cxxxxxbdca3456d6xxxxdd63\""
```

I did not foud a way to right format this guy so the bash would understand.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was not needed the (""), so I just use the following commands:

```bash
etag=$(
    az devops wiki page show\
        --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
        --wiki my_project.wiki \
        --query 'eTag'
    )

az devops wiki page update\
    --path 'my_project - Slab Quality Prediction/test' \
    --wiki my_project.wiki \
    --version ${etag:3:-3} \
    --file-path test.md \
    --encoding utf-8
```

Comment: According to this comment, which seems to be from a guy that works on azure-cli, you could get rid of the outer quotes using `-otsv`: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/1681#issuecomment-271345070 Leaving this here maybe you'd prefer that approach more, even though the one you posted is perfectly fine.